# How to dual write to two columns in one table using Postgres trigger?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, locking

I want to change a column type in PostgreSQL. Let's say from INT to VARCHAR. The safe way to do it is the following:

1. Add a new column `new_<column>`.
2. Dual write to both columns (e.g., with a `BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE` trigger).
3. Backfill the new column with a copy of the old column's values.
4. Rename `<column>` to `old_<column>` `and new_<column>` inside a single transaction and explicit `LOCK <table>` statement.
5. Drop the old column.

The question is how to create this BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger? (2)

Comment: Why not?: `ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN the_col TYPE varchar USING the_col::varchar`

Comment: Depending on the table size you will lock your table for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple table **foo** for this example

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int, idstr varchar);
```

Create a simple function to assign a valur to your new column **idstr**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bluegreen ()
        RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.idstr IS NULL THEN
    NEW.idstr = NEW.id::varchar;
  END IF;
  IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
    NEW.id = NEW.idstr::int;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

And create a trigger on your table with the function previously created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_trg
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE bluegreen();
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html for details on triggers